# Handle the answer of an AJAX POST call to a Rails controller on the front end javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, post

First, I do an AJAX POST call to my rails controller on the front end:

```
var request=$.ajax({
    url: url_up,
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
    data: {q_param: {
             title: title, 
             total: total,
             list: list,
             client: idclient,
             tax_rate: tax_rate 
           }},
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              quote_id=data;
              return false;
            },
    dataType: "json"
    });
```

This call works well and I can see it on the controller side. The controller renders a json answer:

```
def create
      @client=Client.find_by_id(params['q_param']['client'])
      @quote = @client.quotes.create(quote_p)
      render json:  {:quote_id=>@quote.id}
end
```

When doing this, I expect the quote_id variable to have the @quote.id. But it doesn't...
Please could you tell me what's wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: What's wrong is that a validation failed and your quote wasn't saved. Check `@quote.errors` to see what the problem is.

Comment: I don't see any errors as the quote is well stored in DB. By the way tiping the command gives me => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x0000010c37e5a8
 @base=
  #<Quote id: 11, title: "", list: [["", "", "", ""]], total: #<BigDecimal:1013dab88,'NaN',9(9)>, tax_rate: #<BigDecimal:1013dab38,'0.0',9(18)>, starttime: nil, endtime: nil, client_id: 2, created_at: "2014-08-22 01:29:41", updated_at: "2014-08-22 01:29:41">,
 @messages={}>

Comment: Looking at your question again, I think the problem is the following: you're doing `quote_id = data`, but `data` will have the whole JSON. To get the `quote_id`, you have to do `quote_id = data.quote_id`.

Comment: I agree but the issue is that quote_id is undefined at the end: it is not even an object. So I guess the issue is somewhere else in the ajax answer. Thanks for your help

Comment: By the way I tried it and it doesn't work. It stays undefined... thx

Comment: You should use the javascript console to check what is returned in `data`. Try adding `console.log(data);` in your javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your last comment it helped me debug cf the answer I put below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I detected that the data variable in the success method of the AJAX call was getting the json object so instead of doing:

```
quote_id=data;
```

I decided to call a function

```
goShow(data.quote_id);
```

and I could get the good quote id. 
I don't understand why the other method does not work though... 
Thanks to Mischa for his help debugging.